# error while updating table android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

`// ***************************** Error showing in Logcat ************
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: me: , while compiling: UPDATE TemplateTable SET user=?, alert=?, mycard=? WHERE user=me

//********************************* Settings Activity ***************************

Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save_templates);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Save templates selected 
            CardsDatabase db = new CardsDatabase(Settings.this);
            db.open();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(CardsDatabase.USERTEMPLATE, "me");
            cv.put(CardsDatabase.ALERT, Integer.toString(alert));
            cv.put(CardsDatabase.MYCARD, Integer.toString(mycard));
            db.updateTemplate(cv);
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Settings saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

//********************************** Database class******************************

public class CardsDatabase {

```
public static String USERTEMPLATE = "user";
public static String MYCARD = "mycard";
public static String ALERT = "alert";

public static String USER = "user";
public static String NAME = "name";
public static String COMPANY = "company";
public static String TITLE = "title";
public static String ADDRESS = "address";
public static String PHONE = "phone";
public static String CEL = "cel";
public static String EMAIL = "email";
public static String PHOTO = "photo";

public static String MAC = "macaddress";

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "CardsDatabase";
public static String DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE = "TemplateTable";
public static String DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE = "MYTable";
public static String DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "ContactsTable";

private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.d(Tag,"Inner on create called");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE + " ("
                + USERTEMPLATE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + MYCARD
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + ALERT + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE + " (" + USER
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COMPANY
                + " TEXT," + TITLE + " TEXT," + ADDRESS + " TEXT," + PHONE
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + CEL + " TEXT," + EMAIL
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + PHOTO + " BLOB" + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + MAC
                + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public CardsDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public CardsDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public void createEntry(int type, ContentValues cv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (type) {
    case 1:
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, null, cv);
        break;
    case 2:
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE, null, cv);
        break;
    case 3:
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACTS, null, cv);
        break;
    }

}

public Cursor getTemplate() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { USERTEMPLATE, MYCARD, ALERT };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}

public Cursor getMyData() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { USER, NAME, COMPANY, TITLE, ADDRESS,
            PHONE, CEL, EMAIL, PHOTO };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}

public boolean contactExist(String mac) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { MAC };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACTS, columns, MAC
            + "=" + mac, null, null, null, null);

    return c.getCount() > 0 ? true : false;
}

public void updateTemplate(ContentValues cv) {
    String m = "me";
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, cv, USERTEMPLATE + "=" + m,
            null);
}

public void updateMytable(ContentValues cv) {
    String m = "me";
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_MYTABLE, cv, USER + "=" + m, null);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more details, but I'd be willing to bet you updated your schema without incrementing your version number in your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation.

**EDIT**

After looking through your code, you need to add single quotes to your WHERE clause in the update method. If you don't use quotes, the db engine treats it as a column in your table, hence the error "no such column: me"

You have:

```
public void updateTemplate(ContentValues cv) {
    String m = "me";
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, cv, USERTEMPLATE + "=" + m,
            null);
}
```

should be something like:

```
public void updateTemplate(ContentValues cv) {
    String m = "me";
    String WHERE = String.format("%s='%s'", USERTEMPLATE, m);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_TEMPLATE, cv, WHERE, null);
}
```

Comment: i am not updating schema , i am just updating row in which user column contains "me"

Comment: template(user,alert,mycard) these are 3 columns in it .

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around "me" in your query